# Оператор диапазона

Tags: swift

Прохожу курсы по `Swift`, и имеется следующее задание:

> Проверить находится ли введенное число в заданном диапазоне
>   (Range/CountableRange), решение должно быть в одну строчку.
>   (Подсказка: посмотреть на операторы работы с диапазонами).

Моё решение:

```
var number = 11;
switch number {
    case 0...10: print("Входит в диапазон")
    default: print("Не входит в диапазон")
}
```

Куратор говорит, что не правильно. Есть какой-то метод у Range оператора, и запись должна быть в одну строчку.

Основная проблема состоит в том, что использую удаленную машину - компилятор, и не пишу в `IDE` вроде `Xcode`. Все мануалы что я видел - приводят пример исключительно с циклами, но не более.

Подскажите какие методы имеются у этого оператора (методы у оператора 0_о), или хотя-бы ссылку, где можно прочесть про это более подробно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Речь идет о:

```
if 1...10 ~= numberToCheck { }
```

[Описание в документации](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/1539154)